# How to get occurrence of alphabet count at the end of row?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataset on which i want to apply the pivot table.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.array([
        ['vishal','2018-2-1' ,'a' ],
        ['vishal','2018-2-2' , 'n'],
        ['vishal','2018-2-3' , 'n'],
        ['ankti','2018-2-1' , 'a'],
        ['ankti','2018-2-2' , 'n'],
        ['ankti','2018-2-3' , 'n']]),columns=['name', 'date', 'shift'])

name      date      shift
vishal  2018-2-1     a
vishal  2018-2-2     n
vishal  2018-2-3     n
ankti   2018-2-1     a
ankti   2018-2-2     n
ankti   2018-2-3     n
```

i apply the following code to above data set (the above dataset store in df2 variable)

```
table = pd.pivot_table(df2, values='shift', index=['name'], columns=['date'],aggfunc={'shift':np.sum})
print(table)
```

Now I get the following result

output:

```
data      2018-2-1    2018-2-2    2018-2-3
name                            
ankti      a             n            n
vishal     a             n            n
```

Now I want the extra column which contain the extra column which contain the count of **n**

**the final Result should look like as follows**
***the count column show the count of n present in each row***

```
data      2018-2-1    2018-2-2    2018-2-3  count
name                            
ankti      a             n            n      2
vishal     a             n            n      2
```

**NOTE:** if count column without header also fine. i want the count of n at the end of each row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

another way you can do it

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.array([
    ['vishal', '2018-2-1', 'a'],
    ['vishal', '2018-2-2', 'n'],
    ['vishal', '2018-2-3', 'n'],
    ['ankti', '2018-2-1', 'a'],
    ['ankti', '2018-2-2', 'n'],
    ['ankti', '2018-2-3', 'n']]), columns=['name', 'date', 'shift'])
table = pd.pivot_table(df2, values='shift', index=['name'], columns=['date'], aggfunc={'shift': np.sum})
print(table)
table['count'] = table.apply(lambda x: np.sum(x.values == 'n'), axis=1)
```

**output:**

```
date   2018-2-1 2018-2-2 2018-2-3  count
name                                    
ankti         a        n        n      2
vishal        a        n        n      2
```

Comment: You can also try this with a slight modification : `table["count"] = table.apply(lambda row: sum(row[0:]=='n') ,axis=1)`

Comment: NO, you should not, row[0:3] is going to be static,  what if after pivoting table has more columns than 3??, then it will be wrong

Comment: Sandeep's answer is more efficient, i m just pointing out other solution.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`eq`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.eq.html) with [`sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html):

```
table = pd.pivot_table(df2, values='shift', index=['name'], 
                       columns=['data'],aggfunc={'shift':np.sum})

table['count'] = table.eq('n').sum(1)

print(table)
date   2018-2-1 2018-2-2 2018-2-3  count
name                                    
ankti         a        n        n      2
vishal        a        n        n      2
```

Comment: please execute above code.line by line and help me to get final answer

Comment: @Vishal Please learn how to understand answers without asking users to spoon-fed you the solution to the point that you only need copy paste without understanding anything further.